# Export single item to csv Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a model called leads and am trying to export a single lead from my database. Currently I am only able to export all of the leads.

**Model.py**

```
class Lead(models.Model):
   transfer_date=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   callback_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   contact_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   address = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=50)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="")
   state = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
   zipcode = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default="", blank=True)
   cell = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default="", blank=True)
   email = models.EmailField(default="")

   def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

**Views.py**

```
def export(request):
   response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
   writer = csv.writer(response)
   writer.writerow(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email'])

   for lead in Lead.objects.all().values_list('first_name', 'last_name', 'email'):
    writer.writerow(lead)

   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Lead.csv"'

   return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume a separate view for this:

```py
def export_single_lead(request):
   response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
   writer = csv.writer(response)
   writer.writerow(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email'])

   lead = Lead.objects.last()  # Or get the lead you want some other way
   writer.writerow((lead.first_name, lead.last_name, lead.email))

   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Lead.csv"'

   return response
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed my url to include the PK and passed that into the view.

Answer (score -1):

```
def export(request, pk):
   response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')

   writer = csv.writer(response)
   writer.writerow(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email'])


   lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
   writer.writerow((lead.first_name, lead.last_name, lead.email))

  
   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Lead.csv"'

   return response
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).